# Finding optional groups with random order using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get the following using Regex.

This is sample input:

```
-emto=USER@HOST.COM -emfrom=USER@HOST.COM -emsubject="MYSUBJECT"
```

Other input:

```
-emto=USER@HOST.COM -emfrom=USER@HOST.COM -emcc=ME@HOST.COM -embcc=YOU@HOST.COM -emsubject="MYSUBJECT"
```

What I would like to achieve is get named groups using the text after `-em`.
So I'd like to have for example group EMAIL_TO, EMAIL_FROM, EMAIL_CC, ...
Note that I could concat groupname and capture using code, no problem.

Problem is that I don't know how to capture optional groups with "random" positions.
For example, CC and BCC do not always appear but sometimes they do and then I need to
capture them.

Can anybody help me out on this one?!

What I have so far: `(?:-em(?<EMAIL_>to|cc|bcc|from|subject)=(.*))`

Comment: What language? You could split on spaces then on `=`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.
Subject can contain spaces...

Comment: + I'd like to have a regex solution. =)

Comment: what is your app language???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do something like:

```
-em([^\s=]+)=([^\s]+)
```

If you need to support quoting of values, so that they can contain spaces:

```
-em([^\s=]+)=("[^"]*"|[^\s]+)
```

And iterate over all the matches in the command line arg string. For each match, look at the "key" (first capturing group) and see if it is one you recognize. If not, display an error message and exit. If it is, set the option accordingly (the second capturing group is the "value").

**POSTSCRIPT:** This reminds me of a situation which often comes up when writing a grammar for a computer language.

It is possible (perhaps even natural) to write a grammar which only works for syntactically perfect programs. But for good error reporting, it is much better to write a grammar which accepts a *superset* of syntactically correct programs. After you get the parse tree, you can run over it, look for errors, and report them using application-specific code.

In this case, you could write a regex which will only match the options which you actually accept. But then if someone mistypes an option, the regex will simply fail to match. Your program will not be able to provide any specific error messages, regardless of whether the command line args are `-emsubjcet=something` or if they are something completely off the wall like `@@#$*(#&U*REJDFFKDSJ**&#(*$&##`.

**POST-POSTSCRIPT:** Note the very common regex pattern of matching "delimiter + any number of characters which are not a delimiter". In my above regexes, you can see this here: `([^\s=]+)=` -- 1 or more chars which are not whitespace OR =, followed by =. This allows us to easily eat everything which is part of the key, but not go too far and match the delimiting `=`. You can see it again here: `"[^"]*"` -- a quote mark, followed by 0 or more chars which are not a quote mark, followed by a closing quote mark.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the subject when it contains spaces?

Comment: Subject gets broken by space, example input data:

`-emto=USER@HOST.COM -emfrom=USER@HOST.COM -emcc=ME@HOST.COM -embcc=YOU@HOST.COM -emsubject="ALI/PL_LIVE: ZAMÓWIENIE ZAKUPU"`

Comment: OK, I added a regex which can cover that case. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks Alex, but when I test this regex I'm only left with `"ALIPL_LIVE:` ... I think eating while NOT " does not cover the space in subject?

Comment: If I remove the first logical expression for value then I have the subject. So there must be something wrong using OR...?

Comment: This works, but don't ask me why lol. `-em([^\s=]+)=("[^"]*"|[^\s]+)`
I switched the logic for value.

Comment: If you update your answer (and maybe upvote my question :)) I'll mark this as answer!

Comment: Good catch! The problem is that it tries the options in order, and the first one was always matching, so it never made it to the second one.